# "glitschig" (D) vs. "glitch" (E) - Gemeinsame Wurzeln?

Tags: german-to-english, etymology

Haben die sehr ähnlich klingenden und gefühlsmäßig thematisch nahe beieinander stehenden Wörter "the glitch" (E: Verzögerung, Störung, "Macke") und "glitschig" (D: rutschig) von ihrer Entstehungsgeschichte her etwas miteinander zu tun?

Wenn ja, wie kommt es dann, dass in der einen Sprache ein Substantiv und in der anderen ein Adjektiv entsteht?

Comment: Possibly, we don't know. http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=glitch

Answer (score 2):

The English noun “glitch” is first recorded in the 1950s in America. It is a borrowing from Yiddish “glich”, “a slippery place”, which in turn seems to be a back-formation from the German adjective “glitschig”, or perhaps from “Glitschbahn”.

Comment: Da stell' ich mich an und formuliere meine Frage extra auf deutsch und bekomme eine englische Antwort - tsk, tsk, tsk.

Comment: Das ist in der Tat unglücklich.

Comment: Bitte gib eine Quelle an.

Comment: @CarstenS: Keine sehr gute Quelle, aber immerhin plausibel: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=glitch

Comment: Ich frage, weil Du Dir sicherer zu sein scheinst als die Quelle.